# Filter feature with bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to filter my div tags based on their ID using bootstrap. My requirement is similar to this page website [Ashley | One Page Parallax](http://ashley-bootstrap3-website-template.little-neko.com/main/files/index.html#works)
I tried with data-filter but this attribute was not working for me.

Here is my code.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="span12">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
 <li class="active"><a  href="#All">ALL</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Food">Food</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Drinks">Drinks</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Parties">Parties</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Games">Games</a></li>
</ul>
    </div>
    <div class="span12">
        <article class="span6" id="Food">
            Food #1,Food #2,Food #3,Food #..etc,
        </article>
        <article class="span6" id="Drinks">
            Drink #1,Drink #2,Drink #3,Drink #..etc,
        </article>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <div class="span12">
        <article class="span6" id="Parties">
            Party #1,Party #2,Party #3,Party #..etc,
        </article>
        <article class="span6" id="Games">
            Game #1,Game #2,Game #3,Game #..etc,
        </article>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please tell me someone or any working example using bootstrap ?

Comment: haha, if you look through the bootstrap 3 docs you'll notice that it is not one of the functions...

Answer (score 0):

I am answering to my own question, but this is partially solved my problem.

1. Added div IDs in JQuery array variable then created a function. By passing parameter as a div ID it will show appropriate div section and rest of them will be fall in hidden mode.
2. I appreciate if someone can improve this code like add animation features.

Here is my updated code  and [JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sridharnetha/5sYbv/).

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="span12">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li><a href="#" onclick="filterdiv1('ALL')">ALL</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" onclick="filterdiv1('Food')">Food</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" onclick="filterdiv1('Drinks')">Drinks</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" onclick="filterdiv1('Parties')">Parties</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" onclick="filterdiv1('Games')">Games</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="span12">
            <article class="span6" id="Food">
                Food #1,Food #2,Food #3,Food #..etc,
            </article>
            <article class="span6" id="Drinks">
                Drink #1,Drink #2,Drink #3,Drink #..etc,
            </article>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <div class="span12">
            <article class="span6" id="Parties">
                Party #1,Party #2,Party #3,Party #..etc,
            </article>
            <article class="span6" id="Games">
                Game #1,Game #2,Game #3,Game #..etc,
            </article>
        </div>
    </div>
```

JQuery Function:

```
 filterdiv1 = function (id) {
        var idarray = ["Food", "Drinks", "Parties", "Games"];
        if (id != "All") {
            idarray = $.grep(idarray, function (value) {
                return value != id;
            });
            $.each(idarray, function (key, value) {
                $("#" + id).show("highlight");
                $("#" + value).hide("slow");
            });
        }
        if (id == "All") {
            $.each(idarray, function (key, value) {
                $("#" + value).show("slow");
            });
        }
    }
```